# Menu pushing content down

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu

this is the website that I'm doing:
At first, it looks alright but when I resize the window, the menu pushes the banner down. Any thoughts on what could it be ? Thank you

Comment: can you add some code? random link is random

Comment: @gerdi did you want him to include the css for his entire site? Evan Cooper below seemed to answer it fine

Comment: gerdi has a point. A question should include a minimal code sample that reproduces the problem. Not the entire site. Also if you cut it down to the bare minimum you will likely find the problem already.

Comment: Not only that. If the link dies, or the content changes, which it inevitably will, this question won't help anyone in the future without a code sample that explains the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This style is killing your logo float, which is making things sad:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px)
.logo {
  float: none;
}
```

If you omit that style, that should solve the problem.

Comment: @FranciscoCouto flag the answer as accepted then so it may help others